# Изменение первого комита

Tags: git, git-commit, git-revert

В первом (initial) коммите забыл внести файлы в `gitignore` сейчас уже комит 20-й.

**Как можно выйти с ситуации, чтоб в репозиторий запушить ветку без лишних файлов ?**

В удаленный репозиторий ничего не пушил, но описание того что делал важно сохранить.

Возможно ли изменить первый коммит и чтоб те что шли после него уже были без лишних файлов ?

Comment: сделать rebase.

Comment: @KoVadim, а если удалить файлы из индекса git (git rm --cached).
Добавить их в .gitignore. Это может помочь ?

Comment: это поможет только для текущего коммита. В репозитории они остануться.

Comment: @KoVadim, в репозиторий еще ничего не заливал

Comment: как только сделаете push - они будут и в удаленном репозитории. Если коммит делали, то в локальный репозиторий оно уже попало.

Comment: @Maybe_V, репозиторий, это в том числе то что у вас. То куда вы зальете - это тоже репозиторий, но другой, удаленный

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы что-нибудь на удаленный репозиторий пушили после этого?
Если да, то тогда прямо так сделать нельзя, но можно удалить вручную из репозитория файлы, добавленные по ошибке и добавить в гитигнор, и больше они там не появятся.

После уточнения вопроса:
Можно попробовать применить [git rebase с флагом root](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) для того, чтобы создать новую историю от коммита с правильным гитигнором.

Comment: нет. Все пока только локально!

Comment: @Maybe_V, вам ваша история коммитов важна или только текущее состояние? Мусор был в initial commit добавлен?

Comment: история мне важна! Походу да, в initial commit добавлен

Comment: то есть ,если я вас правильно понял: я  сейчас удаляю с проекта все лишнее, добавляю в игнор и комичу ?

Comment: @Maybe_V, нет. Я предлагаю git rm --cached который Вы упомянули сверху. В таком случае файлы действительно останутся в репозитории, что может раздуть размер репы если файлы действительно большие. Но беспокоить они вас не будут.

Comment: @Maybe_V, если вам надо реально чтобы их больше никогда никогда не было, даже в прошлом, то надо ребейзнуться добавив гитигнор в момент их появления. Но так как они у вас добавлены на момент инишл коммита (то есть были всегда), это означает создание вообще нового репозитория)

Comment: О, был неправ, оказывается сейчас есть git rebase root

Comment: спасибо за подсказку! Буду что-то решать)

Comment: @Maybe_V, в общем возможно вам поможет git rebase с флагом --root, но сам я такого не пробовал.

Comment: @Утка поможет, поможет -- даже не сомневайтесь. Постоянно перекраиваю через rebase незакоммиченные изменения, а с этим флагом у меня отпала необходимость и привычка первым же коммитом пихать пустой .gitignore в репозиторий.

Comment: @AK про флаг знаю, но привычка не проходит. )